# Memory Error while Merging Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, memory

I am new to Python and Data Processing. I was trying to process some data just like we use Vtool in excel. I was importing data from 2 excel files and then merge them and extract another excel. I was using pd.merge. However, I am getting memory error.
df1 details:
dtypes: float64(10), int64(1), object(10)
memory usage: 1.0 MB
df2 details:
dtypes: object(6)
memory usage: 579.2 KB

Memory is not even that large. How do I get rid of this memory error?
Here is the code:

```
dff=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(NameList)),columns=['Name'])

dff = pd.merge(dff,df2, how='left',left_on='Name', right_on='Name') 
#From 1st data sheet
dff.drop(['A','B'], axis=1, inplace=True)
dff = pd.merge(dff,df1, how='left',on='Name')
#From 2nd datasheet
dff.drop(['E','F'], axis=1, inplace=True)

dff.index=dff.index+1


display(dff)
```

All I get is the following error:

```
MemoryError
```

---

## Solved

I read individual excel files in different dataframes `df1`,`df2` and `df3` and after dropping certain properties to get rid off the Memory Error I merged them.

```
dff = df2.merge(df1, how='left',on='Name') 

dff.drop(['A','B'], axis=1, inplace=True)
dfff = dff.merge(df3, how='right',on='Name')

dff.drop(['E','F'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode - Please remove any images of code and replace them with a text description/log of the error.

Comment: @SeanPianka: all I get is 'Memory Error'. That's about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that this wouldn't yield some sort of error first.

When you use Pandas `merge` function, you construct it like this:

```
dff = dff.merge(df1, how='left, on='Name') #merge columns are the same so no need to specify right/left
```

Comment: Well it didn't give any error apart from Memory Error.